# AJAX : What is the equivalent function of beforeSend function in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

In $.ajax there is beforeSend function, but now I'm trying to use XMLHttpRequest, I'm looking for equivalent function of beforeSend in $.ajax. How can i implement it in here.

Here is my xhr code,

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = '../ajax/ajax_edit/update_ajax_staffUser.php';

    if(file.files.length !== 0){

        if(!check(fileUpload.type)){
            alert("This file format not accepted");
            return false;
        }
        xhr.open('post', url+param, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', fileUpload.name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', fileUpload.size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type', fileUpload.type);
        xhr.send(fileUpload);
    }else{
        xhr.open('post', url+param, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
        xhr.send(fileUpload);
    }


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e){
        if(xhr.readyState===4){
            if(xhr.status==200){
                $('.bounce_dim').show();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.trigger_danger_alert_changable_success').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
                    $('#palitan_ng_text_success').html('User successfully modified');
                    $('#frm_edit_staffUser')[0].reset();
                    $('#modal_staff').modal('hide');
                    $('.bounce_dim').hide();
                },1000);
                getUserStaffTable();
            }
        }
    }
```

Since the users are uploading image to my web, I need to make a waiting interface before fires the call since the image size are too large.

Comment: beforesend is just a function that executes before the ajax call is sent, it's nothing special? Are you planning on getting rid of the rest of the jQuery dependant code, including those animations, as well? Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: No I mean, when i click the button it should pop up first the loading animation until the image totally upload.  What happen is when i click the button user will not identify if the picture is still uploading or not. Besides, i don't want users to make an action on my page while the picture still uploading

Comment: Also because, I'm putting the animation inside the beforeSend in my other $.ajax code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by just putting the *beforeSend()* function before your XHR intantiation, like this:

```
beforeSend();
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

But you should define your *beforeSend()* function before the code above:

```
var beforeSend = function(){
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Adding `beforeSend` before `xhr.send(fileUpload)` would be more closer equivalent. Calling before instantiation does not seem right.

Answer (score 3):

`.beforeSend` just calls the function before running `.send`, so just put your code before the line:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', fileUpload.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', fileUpload.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type', fileUpload.type);
beforeSend(); // Put any code to run before sending here
xhr.send(fileUpload);
```

Comment: Is this mean that i will wrapped my codes into $.ajax beoreSend?

Comment: @EchoingThroughoutTelNumara No, see updated answer. `beforeSend` is literally just any code before sending.